# How to display php image gallery inside a div?

Tags: php, html

My website has two div columns: a vertical navigation menu and main content. I used php to navigate different pages of my website to the main div ([similar to this php example](http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/create-simple-website-php_t))...(eg. index.php?pg=about_us --> get content from /page/about.html). But one of the pages I want to display this gallery (http://sye.dk/sfpg/) on the main div.

How to display my gallery correctly in the main div (installed under /pages/gallery/index.php) (eg. width about 700px)? I have the same problem if the navigation menu is pointed to an external website.  (let's say google) The size and charset are not displayed correctly while using div. Thank you.

```
<?php
  // ...blah blah blah
  $pgname = isset($_GET['pg']) ? trim(strip_tags($_GET['pg'])) : 'index';
  //....
?>

// starts html, header and body
<div class="left_col">  
  <nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=news" title="News">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=gallery" title="Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=donate" title="Donate">Donate</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.php?pg=about_us" title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="main_col clearfix">         
  <?php                                     
    if ($pgname != 'gallery'){      
        echo file_get_contents('pages/'. $pgname. '.html');     
    } else {
        echo file_get_contents('http://google.com/'); // this doesn't work, and neither work with '/pages/gallery/index.php'
    }
  ?>                    
</section>
```

Comment: What does the code look like on `/pages/gallery/index.php` ?

Comment: if the `php` resource is on your server why not just `include` it instead of `file_get_contents`?

Comment: yeah, if you echo the contents of a php page, the php parts will not be processed. if you use include then the php parts will get processed.

Comment: php couldn't care less about the structure of your page. it does what you tell it do. if you want your gallery stuff to show up inside a div, then you have to structure your code to make it happen, e.g. `<div><?php include('gallery.html'); ?></div>` and of course, you have to make sure what you're outputting is actually VALID for that context. you can't spit out a complete html page inside another page - you have to generate VALID html

Comment: @MarcB is exactly on point. You need to make sure the syntax works when both files are combined. Use tools like [this](https://validator.w3.org/) to help validate.

Comment: Re @Pamblam: http://sye.dk/sfpg/ there is only one file to download

Comment: @SarahYung - that is not a file. i'm not gonna read the whole page, just post what was asked for.

Comment: that file has 3666 lines of code in a single index.php file. i don't think i could paste it here.

Comment: we don't need the entire page, especially if large chunks are just repetitive.

Answer (score 2):

Simplified, the above becomes:

gallery.php:

```
<?php
    $name = 'gallery'; // Fixed for this example.
    $html_gallery = 'pages/'. $name . '.html';
?>
<html>
    <section>
        <?php include $html_gallery ?>
    </section>
</html>
```

pages/gallery.html:

```
<img src="/images/foo.jpg">
<img src="/images/bar.jpg">
<img src="/images/baz.jpg">
```

gallery.php would render much like this:

```
<html>
    <section>
        <img src="/images/foo.jpg">
        <img src="/images/bar.jpg">
        <img src="/images/baz.jpg">
    </section>
</html>
```

So as you can see, it is up to you to style the output.

Comment: getting a bit dizzy thinking about this over n over~~

Comment: sorry, i m not so sure about what you mean by making another gallery.html? so maybe i have to explain more: everything is displayed in the homepage (index.php). After clicking the navigation menu, the main div displays content from other html pages. the gallery is pre-made by someone in php format..(think it like an external site like google)

Comment: I called it gallery.php just so I could refer to it.  Let's call it page.php.  I understand your problem now, you are swallowing the output of a php script (single file gallery) which outputs as an entire html page.  You are trying to sandwich that HTML into existing HTML.  You could perhaps use an iframe.  From the readme of SFPG:  Single File PHP Gallery version 4.x is a stand-alone gallery. It is not designed to be included on existing pages. This is by design.

Answer (score 0):

I like your idea a lot... but I think it would be much easier for you to use JavaScript and AJAX for this. Also, this approach will prevent the page from reloading!

**EDIT -** So, if you say you have both HTML and PHP files to use, an `ext` parameter (extension) in your events will do the trick. **- EDIT**

My idea would be to give an `onclick` event on each `li` calling a JavaScript function, let's say `onclick="getContent(page, ext)"`. So of course you need to replace `page` to whatever string you like, let's say `gallery`; and `ext` to any extension you need as a string, let's say `php`.

Sample result:

```
<li onclick="getContent('news', 'html')" title="News">News</li>
<li onclick="getContent('gallery', 'php')" title="Gallery">Gallery</li>
```

Now, let's build our JavaScript-AJAX stuff. What we first need to do is create the function and place it right after the `<body>` tag inside a `<script>` tag, of course. Then remember to add an `id` to your main column, in the following example it will be `content`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getContent(pageName, ext){
    var url = "pages/"+pageName+"."+ext, // gallery.php - news.html
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

So now this function creates the request and gets the data from your URL and then places **all** the HTML in it inside your `section`. Of course, make sure that the HTML file contains only what you need inside the `section`.

Your main column in HTML should look like this:

```
<section class="main_col clearfix" id="content"></section>
```

**- EDIT -**

About the pre-made single file PHP gallery and resizing problem... I saw the demo and I think I know how it works... my advice is to make sure you set a width to your `main_col` section because the content given by the demo seems to be lots of `div`'s with a class `thumbbox` which happens to be arranged by CSS `display:inline-block` so it should just work fine like that.

But the biggest problem I see is that once you load the content on your page, it will not work unless you `include();` (PHP) the file or at least the source code for your single page PHP gallery, because you will only load the HTML and I also see that it uses the JavaScript `onclick` event just like my idea.

What I can say is that to help you solve this thing entirely, I should be able to see how you're implementing this library and many other things. I think you can work it out tho if you include the file like I said (so that the PHP code loads and hopefully prints the necessary JavaScript).

Also, the charset might be solved using PHP `utf8_encode();` or `utf8_decode();`. Use the first one to encode from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 and the second one for the other way round.

Comment: i m happy to try this later, but the gallery is in pre-made in php format (n sizing problem again...?), and other pages are html (they look fine).

Comment: You can still load .php files with this method, what will happen is that the php will run and whatever it outputs will appear on your column. Supposing that you want to mix .html and .php or any other format, you can pass the extension as a parameter so that you can specify it on the `onclick` event. I'll edit and show you. The sizing problem is more of a HTML-CSS thing that you can sort out in different ways. I'll try to give you a small example in my edit and let's see if it fits your needs.

Comment: And by the way... I'm using `section` only because you are using it, but using a `div` won't be a problem as long as you sort out the CSS `width`, `display`, `position` and/or `vertical-align`, `float`. I usually set the small column with a fixed size, let's say 300px and then use `width:calc(100% - 310px);` in the other, plus the other properties to make it look nice. And calc needs -webkit- and -moz- prefixes.